# Validate Phone Number & Email Address in same input field

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation

I am in need to validate phone number & email address in same input field that if user enters letters then it should be show email validation & if user tries to enter phone number it should show the phone number validation. Please help on this issue. I am using bootstrap validator from this http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/

Comment: Could you please add a little more description about the problem you have?

Comment: Overall I want to validate email address & phone number in a form but in same input field. I want that
1. if user had filled wrong email id then a alert should be seen said "Please Enter Correct Email Id".
2. If user wants to fill a phone number & if he had filled incorrect phone number than a alert should be seen says "Please Enter Correct Phone No."

I WANT THIS TO BE IN SINGLE INPUT FIELD..

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like the above answer is good, but wanted to pass along my response as well. Looks like the same but may have more robust phone number handling.Also demos jquery form submit event handling which is a pattern I prefer.
https://jsfiddle.net/joedonahue/8vasb4nu/9/

```
<!--HTML-->
<form id="myform" name="myform" action="/echo/html/" method="post">
    <input type="text" id="myinput" name="myinput" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form> 

<!--JavaScript-->    

/* Get Values */
var i1 = $("#myinput");

/* Map Event Handler */
$("#myform").on("submit",validate);

/* Validate Function */
function validate(){

    /* Phone Test */
    var filter = /^((\+[1-9]{1,4}[ \-]*)|(\([0-9]{2,3}\)[ \-]*)|([0-9]{2,4})[ \-]*)*?[0-9]{3,4}?[ \-]*[0-9]{3,4}?$/;
    if (filter.test(i1.val())) {
        alert("true!");
        return true;
    }

    /* Email Test */
    var filter = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;
    if (filter.test(i1.val())) {
        alert("true!");
        return true;
    }

    alert("false!");
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks I like it :) I will apply this jquery to my one & let know any issues

Comment: Thanks, Ali. Please remember to "Mark as Answer" if you use it and upvote as well :)

Answer (score 1):

Email and phone validation using jquery..**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/sheshu036/h4m311cL/2/)**

```
$('#sub').click(function(){
var ep_emailval = $('#email').val();
console.log(ep_emailval);
    var intRegex = /[0-9 -()+]+$/;

if(intRegex.test(ep_emailval)) {
   console.log("is phone");
   if((ep_emailval.length < 9) || (!intRegex.test(ep_emailval)))
{
     alert('Please enter a valid phone number.');
     //return false;
}

}
    else
    {
 var eml = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;       
        console.log("is email");
        if (eml.test(ep_emailval) == false) {
    alert("Please enter valid email address.");
   // $("#<%=txtEmail.ClientID %>").focus();
    //return false;
 }
    }
});
```

Comment: OP said _validate phone number & email address in same input field_ ? I am afraid your answer is not what OP is looking for.,.

Comment: Nice one but if you enter more than 9 or exact 9 numbers it will give `Uncaught ReferenceError: phone is not defined`. Did you check that??

Comment: Updated your answer!! Update the fiddle accordingly!! You where passing `(!intRegex.test(phone)` phone here which wasn't there!

Comment: Thanks but it has some issues I wil let you know @shri